# String-fun_to_remove a commnt

Tags: c

I have a function to remove a comment, or more than one, but I don't understand how it works.

How do the loops work? There is

```
for(j+=2; s[++j] && (s[j-1]!='*' || s[j]!='/' || !j++); );
```

Why does !j++ work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void remove_cmmnt(char *s)
{ int k=0;
        char *p=s;

        for( k=0;p[k];k++);
    char T[k];
    int i,j;
    for(i=j=0; s[j] ;  )
    {

        if(s[j]=='/' &&  s[j+1]=='*')
            for(j+=2; ++j && (s[j-1]!='*' || s[j]!='/' || !j++); );
        else
            T[i++]=s[j++];
    }

        printf("%s",T);

    s[i]='\0';
}
```

Comment: First attempt to format the code consistently. Then use a *debugger* to step through the code line by line. It could also help to split complex expressions and statements into multiple smaller expressions and statements.

Comment: If you don't understand how, I suggest you rewrite the code. *Your for loop is absolutely not idiomatic*

Comment: A finite state machine would yield more readable code, IMHO.(and you should probably handle strings, too)

Comment: thank u !! sry for my code i am new here i wish u the best!

Comment: Please check if you copied the code without errors. In your question you cite `for(j+=2; s[++j] && (s[j-1]!='*' || s[j]!='/' || !j++); );` but the code block contains `for(j+=2; ++j && (s[j-1]!='*' || s[j]!='/' || !j++); );` `s[++j]` checks if the next character is not 0 (probably correct), `++j` checks if the next **index** is not 0 (probably wrong).

Comment: the both work good and make the same

Comment: `s[++j]` as the first part of the `for` loop's condition will terminate the loop when the end of the string is reached. This would handle a string that ends before terminating the comment, e.g. `some_function(); /* incomplete comment`. In contrast to this `++j` at the same place would terminate the loop when the index wraps around to 0 which is most likely not what you want. I think the `s[i]='\0';` after the `printf` is wrong. It should be `T[i]='\0';` before the `printf`

Comment: thank u for reply ! ur right ! i traied.

Comment: but for(i=j=0; s[j] ;  ) will work alon like this :
s[0],s[1]...'\0' ? or how ??

Comment: `!j++` doesn't make sense, the check will likely be optimized away by the compiler since `j` will never get back to `0`. This code will fail if the comment is not terminated, because the inner loop doesn't check for null characters. The `(s[j-1]!='*' || s[j]!='/' || !j++)` is a really bad piece of C code, do yourself a favor, delete it and write it from scratch.

Comment: i didnt understand too !j++ what that meaning ?!

Comment: @M.Rostom: it means "repeat the loop until `j` becomes `0`", which will never happen. Ask yourself what happens if you pass a string which does not terminate its comment, e.g. `"something /* comment"`. It's also a bad practice to increment the variable inside the conditional expression, standard form of the for loop statement is `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { ... }`, and you should stick to it.

Comment: when i remove !j++ it donst work good

Comment: @Groo Why did you vote "unclear what you're asking"? There are two clear questions "How do the loops work?" and "Why does !j++ work?".

Comment: @M.Rostom You wrote "sry for my code". I don't believe that you wrote it because it's written in a very strange way which requires some knowledge while you didn't understand it. Now that you know what it does you should rewrite it in a more readable style.

Comment: I guess the `s[i]='\0';` is from the original source of this code which did not create the result in a separate array `T` but modified the original string `s`. Use your favourite search engine to find "remove_cmmnt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some explanation with two fixes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void remove_cmmnt(char *s)
{ 
    int k=0;

    char *p=s; // The additional pointer is unnecessary, you could use 's' instead of 'p' in the next line.
    for( k=0;p[k];k++); // the same as k = strlen(s); probably one byte too short for array size

    k++; // added to fix wrong array size

    char T[k]; // array should be big enough to hold original string including '\0'

    int i,j; // j is source index, i is destination index
    for(i=j=0; // initialize source and destination index
        s[j] // terminate loop if we reached end of source string
        ;  ) // no explicit incrementing of a loop index
    {

        if(s[j]=='/' &&  s[j+1]=='*') // start of comment at current and next position. We can check 2 characters because the loop condition already checked for not '\0' and at least the terminating '\0' should follow.
            for(j+=2; // skip 2 characters ('/' and '*')
                // The complicated condition with index incrementing makes use of short-circuit evaluation
                s[++j] && // always evaluated. increment index, terminate loop if end of string is reached.
                (s[j-1]!='*' || // continue loop and stop evaluating condition if previous character is not 1st char '*' of comment termination
                s[j]!='/' || // continue loop and stop evaluating condition if current char is not 2nd char '/' of comment termination
                !j++) // This is reached only if we found the end of the comment. Increment index and (because normally j!=0) evaluate as false to terminate the loop. This skips the terminating '/' we have just found.
                ; ); // no explicit incrementing of a loop index
        else // if we didn't find a comment start
            T[i++]=s[j++]; // copy current character from original to modified copy
    }

    T[i]='\0'; // T instead of s as in the question and before printf. terminate modified copy.
    printf("%s",T);
}
```

Comment: thanks man !!! can i give u 10 euro just like small thanks

Comment: @M.Rostom No, but you can donate to a charitable organization: https://www.ekp.de/ On the top left there should be a yellow button with the text "Spenden" (=donate).

Comment: sorry if we wirt char *str"'HALLO /*5435efg*/WEL/*T";
it will think that /* comment too how i can fix it to know that not allowd to delete becouse its not a comment

Comment: @M.Rostom Sorry, it was some fun to analyze and explain the strange code, but it is bad design and very difficult to extend. If you want to modify the code, please rewrite it in a readable and idiomatic manner first. When you are done you should ask a separate question about your difficulties to add string handling. (Also think of `\"` in a string.) See wildplassers's comment about a finite state machine. (BTW: Don't copy bad code and pretend that you have written it. You might get into trouble when you get questions about it.)